# Combining multiple .rds files into one

Tags: r, r-sf

I have multiple .rds files that I need to combine into one .rds file.

```
[1] "RDS_Species/SeaTurtles/Caretta_caretta_IUCN.rds"       
[2] "RDS_Species/SeaTurtles/Chelonia_mydas_IUCN.rds"        
[3] "RDS_Species/SeaTurtles/Dermochelys_coriacea_IUCN.rds"  
[4] "RDS_Species/SeaTurtles/Eretmochelys_imbricata_IUCN.rds"
[5] "RDS_Species/SeaTurtles/Lepidochelys_olivacea_IUCN.rds"
```

I was able to make them into one list:

```
SeaTurtles_IUCNdist <- list.files(path="RDS_Species/SeaTurtles/",
                                  pattern = ".rds$", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  map(readRDS)
```

The .rds files are data.frame files. How should I proceed in order to combine them into one large .rds file?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map_dfr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
SeaTurtles_IUCNdist <- list.files(path="RDS_Species/SeaTurtles/",
                              pattern = ".rds$", full.names = TRUE) %>%
         map_dfr(readRDS)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! But when I tried to save it I got this error: 
`> st_write(SeaTurtles_IUCNdist, "RDS_Species/RasterStacks/AllSeaTurtles_IUCNdist.rds")
Error: Could not guess driver for RDS_Species/RasterStacks/AllSeaTurtles_IUCNdist.rds`

Comment: Never mind! Just figured what I was doing wrong with the saving!!! Thanks a lot!